# Why would Visual Studio 2005 change the StackReserveSize when upgrading a vcproj file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, chm

I have a very old C++ application that was being built with Visual C++ Version 7.0 when I inherited it. When I brought it forward to Visual Studio 2005, the conversion routine apparently changed the value of StackReserveSize from "0" to "66112".

I probably never would have noticed this change if it had not manifested into stack overflow problems with calls to HtmlHelp. The program would overflow and crash everything whenever the help file search function was used. Once I changed the StackReserveSize back to "0", no more stack overflows.

So does anyone know why VS2005 would change this value or what implications might arise if I change it back to "0"?

Comment: Who knows?  Just set it back to 0.

Comment: That's pretty much my attitude, but I figured that someone may have seen it before.